# Select multiple databases with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have a `functions.php` file that has one `PDO` Connection i use to access the database and all that good stuff it's this one:

```
$host = "localhost";
$db = "maindatabase";
$adminuser = "admin";
$adminpw = "123456";
global $connection;

$connection = new Connection($host,$adminuser,$adminpw,$db);
```

And i `require` this script on every file that needs to access to the database, the thing is in some cases i want to change from `$db = "maindatabase";` to `$db = "anotherdb";` and i know i can do it with just a setter

```
$connection->setDatabase("anotherdb");
```

But since i `require` the `functions.php` file into every other file i don't know if it will overwrite itself back to default, does anybody knows how can i change it and make it stay ?

**EDIT**

I have changed `require` to `require_once` in my code and since the PHP Documentation says if the file has already been *required* it will not add it again, do you think this will solve the issue ?

Comment: Does functions.php wrap this code up in any way? If this is in a class, you could make a call in each page script to a constructor, supplying the database name in each case. Anyway: this is the reason for using a framework of some kind - you can do initialisation stuff in a parent controller, or some other initialisation section, depending on a routing variable or some other testable condition.

Comment: Yeah actually i made the class `Connection` which is the one `functions.php` it's referring to.

Comment: That's not what I mean. I mean if you are including functions and creating a global object in there, then you've created a Connection that in some cases you won't use. It's best to run the code that creates connections once, depending one what database you want to connect to.

Comment: i only include `functions.php` on the files that need it. besides the user will choose the database connection at the start of the system and it will work with that database from there on

Comment: _the user will choose the database connection at the start of the system and it will work with that database from there on_ - you mean stored in a session? That's fine, but it still doesn't answer the question as to how you'll arrange some pages to access one db, and have other pages access another db.

Comment: I just need them to every single query to point to the same database choosen at the start of the system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the **classic** problem with global variables. Your program state is unpredictable. You can't know which database you're referring to.

Your solution is proper dependency injection.

Implement a factory class to generate the correct database connection on demand, and don't use global variables. That's the **correct** solution.

Comment: I wish i new about this before i started my project, thanks a lot anyways

Answer (score 2):

You may make two connections for every database

```
$host = "localhost";
$db1 = "maindatabase";
$db2 = "anotherdb";
$adminuser = "admin";
$adminpw = "123456";
global $connection1, $connection2;

$connection1 = new Connection($host,$adminuser,$adminpw,$db1);
$connection2 = new Connection($host,$adminuser,$adminpw,$db2);
```

Comment: Since the system it's going to be used by a lot of users don't think it's a good idea

Comment: If the connections are persistent, I don't think this will add much overhead - have you measured the performance impact? (If no, then so long as your approach is modular, it will be easy to tweak later).

Comment: @IsaacGonzalez: well, that's a big enough topic to warrant a question on its own. But (a) use `ab` or some similar testing tool, and (b) if you aren't maxing out a capable server yet, then don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

It may get ugly depending on your level of analness when it comes to pretty code, but why not specifiy the database prefix in your query if the MySQL user has access to both databases?

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM maindatabase.tablename WHERE this='that';
```

On your other function, do:

```
SELECT * FROM anotherdb.tablename WHERE this='that';
```

You can also do:

```
$database_name = 'maindatabase';
$query = "SELECT * FROM {$database_name}.table";

$database_name = 'anotherdb';
$query = "SELECT * FROM {$database_name}.table";
```

This way you can toggle your `$database_name` variable where needed.

Comment: Yeah i don't think that's a good idea, i have like a LOT of querys in my code and i think there must be an easier way to do this, than add if statements to every query