# Transfer mysql table between two databases with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been researching this for the past hour, and yet to come up with a simple solution that doesnt involve some weird exports/imports.

All I am trying to do is open up a PDO connection with two databases so that I can use them both in queries.

It seems that there is disagreements in Stack Overflow about this.

One answer:

> ...you will need to create two PDO objects for the seperate
>   connections if you would like to use both at runtime.

But others seem to suggest you can just "use" two databases in your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbname.tablename";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM anotherdbname.anothertablename"
```

I tried preforming a SELECT command on another database besides the one explicitly defined in my PDO connection function. I got this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1142 SELECT
>   command denied to user 'dbusername'@'localhost' for table
>   'table_name'

I made sure to add the user to both databases and grant full privileges.

Is a query that uses two databases in the same connection possible? Or do you have to setup two different objects?

Comment: Did you remember to flush privs after doing the grants?  Because that error is *all* about the grants.

Comment: I'm not sure...:( How do I flush privileges?

Comment: I simply used my cPanel to add the user to the other database and granted all privileges.

Comment: *cPanel*.  Oh.  Yeah, that should have [flushed](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html) for you.  It didn't, or it malfunctioned.

Comment: So I am out of luck then with that SELECT query?

Comment: Oh, no, it *should* be working.  Try resetting the grant?  Maybe run a `SHOW GRANTS`?

Comment: I used a SHOW GRANT and it only showed privileges for one database...I think, like the answer below, it has something to do with the fact that only one db is specified when you initiate PDO.

Comment: Oh, wait, you're using *one* connection to talk to both databases?  No can do unless you're using the *same* credentials on the *same* server.  One connection each.  Two different sets of credentials means you need two connections.  If you're just issuing `USE foo` to switch at run-time, that should work.  Maybe you should show us the code that's failing instead of just the summary?  I still think this is busted grants....

Comment: I switched everything to use the same credentials (and yes, same server) but it still won't work. How do I get it to connect to both OR how do I setup queries after doing one connection each?

Comment: WHOA it worked suddenly after making the credentials the same. Thank you so much!

Comment: You should post that as a solution -- you reset the credentials and made sure that the single user could access both databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out preforming a query across two databases *is* possible with a single PDO connection. Even though **one** database is defined in my PDO initiation, I still have access to another database.

The solution is to make both databases have the same credentials.

```
function db_connect(){
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 3306; // This is the default port for MySQL
$database = 'db1';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$database";

$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
return $db;
}

$db=db_connect();
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM db2.table LIMIT 1");
$statement->execute();
$x=$statement->fetchObject();
var_dump($x); //A full row from the table was the output.
```

Comment: Then are you using ->exec() to execute SQL queries across multiple databases?

Answer (score 2):

"a PDO connection with two databases" (singular form) is a misnomer, because by definition a PDO connection is a single connection to a single data store. If you want two connections, you will need to instantiate two instances.

Comment: What would be the best way to transfer a full table then?

Comment: And does that mean this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11636017/1019588 is completely invalid?

Comment: The problem is that the answer you provided is not a valid PHP PDO answer. It would definitely work with the mysqli_query() functions, because there you can use mysqli_select_db() to actually change the database of your connection. You cannot do that with a PDO.

Comment: Okay, so some more research makes it seem like the db.table syntax is available for raw mysql commands, but not when going through PHP. Correct?

Comment: Yes, but also remember that a PDO instance requires a specific database as an initialization parameter. That is the single limiting factor of the PDO versus using mysqli* functions. But even then, a PDO helps to compartmentalize data, which really is a good thing, even if you want to put a bunch of stuff from database_a into database_b.

Comment: But he don't need two connections actually.

Answer (score 0):

> I made sure to add the user to both databases and grant full privileges.

The error message is quite unambiguous. Reading this, I wouldn't be so sure.

Anyway, to answer the title question:
Why not to just run this simple query from the console?

```
INSERT INTO db2.table SELECT * FROM db1.table;
```

It will not only transfer your data but also will prove if your users have sufficient rights or not.
If not - you have to really make sure that.

Comment: Because "All I am trying to do is open up a PDO connection"